# Using Spring4 AsyncRestTemplate in a method which uses an @Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, rest, asynchronous

I am using the Spring4 *AsyncRestTemplate* to make calls to an External REST API service.

The method below is from a Spring *@Service* class.  The *AsyncRestTemplate* is autowired from a Spring *@Bean*.

In the method, I register callbacks on the *ListenableFuture* response from the REST API call.

I don't use the returned *ListenableFuture* except for unit tests.  The callbacks will handle the actual actions I want to take based on request success or failure.

**ExternalServiceImpl.class**

```
public ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseBody>> makeExternalCall(RequestBody requestBody) {

            HttpEntity<RequestBody> request = new HttpEntity<>(RequestBody, getDefaultHeaders());

            ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseBody>> responseEntity = asyncRestTemplate.exchange(serviceUri.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, request, ResponseBody.class);

            responseEntity.addCallback(
                    (onSuccess) -> System.out.println("Success"), 
                    (onFailure) -> onFailure.printStackTrace()
            );

            return responseEntity;
    }
```

I plan on using the @EnableAsync annotation and setting up a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor as well as adding an @async annotation to the method in a manner similar to the procedure described here:  [Spring Asynchronous Methods](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

**Questions**

- Is this redundant?  Is there an additional benefit to scaling when
  making the method async even though I'm using an
  *AsyncRestTemplate*?
- Is there anything considered best practice that I'm missing in
  implementing this pattern?
- Is there anything to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

`@Async` doesn't actually do anything until you add the `@EnableAsync` annotation to your application.  When that happens, any code calling your `makeExternalCall` method will immediately return, and spring will look for a `TaskExecutor` bean to run the whole method asynchronously (rather than just your `asyncRestTemplate` service being the only async part of your code currently).

More info on the spring website: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer my question.  The article I linked shows how to configure an application including the @EnableAsync annotation and setting up an ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

Comment: Ok, I was just pointing out the difference between using @Async and just an AsyncRestTemplate as I thought that's what you were asking. Based on my further reading, AsyncRestTemplate calls will be passed to spring's SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.  Given this approach doesn't re-use threads, using a thread pooling TaskExecutor could give you better performance, hence better scaling :) And I don't see why you'd ever need to synchronize it either if you were running it inside a spring managed container.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I suspected what you are stating is true, I was just looking for a more detailed answer.  Fyi, AsyncRestTemplate only uses the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor if you use the parameterless constructor.